# How to find my clan without bookmarking

Tags: clash-of-clans

I forgot to bookmark my war clan before leaving. Is there any way to find that clan?

Comment: Flagging for a hold, since it is unclear what the user is asking about.

Comment: Well, those edits help... sorry, my bad!

Answer (score 5):

If you have received any clan mail while in that clan, you can go to your your mail inbox and tap on one of the messages and click view clan to find it. Otherwise you can search with the clan search functionality, though you will need at least the clan name and any additional information you remember will help you narrow it down. If you happen to remember the clan tag, you can easily find the clan using the search, as clan tags are unique so searching by it will give you the clan you are looking for.